# configuring a remote mail server (google app) in cpanel

Tags: email, server

I have pointed a domain on ixwebhosting with ixweb namserver also i am using the the google apps email which is also configure in the ixweb. But my domain is now on different server pointed from ixweb with A record so how should enter mx record so that my mail server works with ixweb, i am using cpanel now?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Google email service. You just need to set required MX records from DNS management section from where you are managing your domain name DNS records.

As you have said that, you have set nameservers to point ixwebhosting server so you can manage your domain DNS records from cPanel. Following are required steps to set your domain MX/mail service to Google:

1. Log into your Cpanel.
2. Click the MX Entry icon.
3. Select your domain ame from the drop-down list, for which you want to set MX records.
4. Choose Automatically Detect Configuration and hit the Change button.
5. Under "Add New Record", enter your Google MX records.
6. Click on "Add New Record" button to save the changes.

Also, make sure that you remove ixwebhosting MX records so it will not conflict MX records and you do not face any problem in email service.

Once you add Google records, it will take sometime for DNS propagation. If you do not see MX entry Icon in cPanel or you do not have expertise on DNS modification, recommend to contact hosting provider support to setup this for you.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to do this, but we will require more information. Have you added A record pointing to a different server from Domain control panel or your hosting control panel.

If you have pointed A record from Domain control panel then you will still be using nameserver of ixwebhosting and MX record of Google. So you can login into your hosting control panel and change your existing MX records from google to ixwebhosting. You can get MX records from ixwebhosting.

Answer (score 0):

The steps provided by Herbal are fine, But forget to add one more step to to set Email Routing as Remote Mail Exchanger. It is required.